# Oracle PL-SQL function not returning on true

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, boolean, return

I am trying to write a function that returns a 1 if it finds the account description already in the table and a 0 if it does not.

I can get it to return the 0 fine, but I cant seem to get it to return 1

```
    Create or replace function test_glaccounts_description
    ( 
    var_account_desc varchar2
    )
    return number
    as var_status number
    begin
    select 1 into var_status
    from general_ledger_accounts
    where account_description = var_account_desc;
    exception
    when no_data_found then
    var_status := 0;
    return var_status;
    end;
    /
```

This is what it is supposed to do

Code a function named test_glaccounts_description that accepts one parameter
that tests whether an account description is already in the
General_Ledger_Accounts table. This function should return a value of 1 if the
account description is in the table or zero if it isn't. (Note: If a SELECT
statement doesn't return any data, it throws a NO_DATA_FOUND exception
that your function can handle.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return from all paths in your code.

Something like this should work:

```
begin
  select 1 into var_status
    from general_ledger_accounts
    where account_description = var_account_desc;
  return var_status;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    var_status := 0;
    return var_status;
end;
/
```

Comment: ah I did not know an exception was considered a separate part thanks.